# how to use foreignKey?

Tags: python, django

how to use foreignKey?

please help retrieve and display data using foreignKey

[models.py](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/fk.jpg):

```
class Gender(models.Model):     
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        blank=False,
    )   

class UserProfile(User):
    name1 = models.CharField(
        'Имя',
        max_length=30, 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    gender = models.ForeignKey(
        Gender,
        default=0,
    )
```

fixtures:

```
[
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "none"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "gender": "male"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "drummersaransk.Gender",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
        "gender": "female"
        }
    }   
]
```

views.py:

```
def user_personal(request, id):     
    entries_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id=id)          

    t = loader.get_template('user_personal.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'entries_user_profile': entries_user_profile,
    })  
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

user_personal.html:

```
{% if entries_user_profile.gender_id %}
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Пол</td>

        <td class="gender info">{{ entries_user_profile.gender_id }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

the problem is that gender is not output value from the table Gender (none, male or female)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You outs `gender.id`, not gender name.

Try to replace this

`<td class="gender info">{{ entries_user_profile.gender_id }}</td>`

with this

`<td class="gender info">{{ entries_user_profile.gender.gender }}</td>`

**UPDATE**

Maybe `choices` is a better way to store users gender. Check it out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices